# eat the most something/eat something the most

Tags: meaning

> 1 She ate the most meat.
>
> 2 She ate meat the most.

I am not quite clear on what they mean.

**Does one mean: a) She ate meat the most of all the people. b) She ate meat the most than any other food.**

**Does two mean: a) She ate meat the most than any other food.**

Comment: We can't say **the most than**. (2) isn't particularly idiomatic, but it would probably be understood to mean 'She ate meat more often than any other food'.

Comment: Version #2 is *very* unusual phrasing (possibly syntactically invalid, I'm not sure). Hence the meaning isn't clear, but I'd be inclined to interpret it as *She **mostly** ate meat* (she ate meat more than she ate anything else). Your final *She ate meat the most than any other food* is definitely invalid. You need to learn the syntax of ***most***.

Comment: She ate meat the most of any other food.

Comment: That isn't idiomatic either. It has to be _more than any other_ or _meat was the type of food she ate the most_.

Answer (score 1):

1 does mean she ate more than the other people. 2 probably means she ate meat more than other food (that was my first instinct), but could mean the same as 1. Out of context 2 is ambiguous whereas 1 is not.